# Filling in the NaN values with Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, nan, missing-data

I have x1=Job level (numerical), x2= Job code (categorical) and y = Stock value (numerical). For a data set of 3x500 i have 250 NaN values in Stock Value.

What do I need to change in my code below to read x2 as a categorical value and rerun the program to find the coefficients?[Data set example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsn7S.png)

```
> import pandas as pd from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
> df = pd.read_excel("stats.xlsx")
> df_nonull=df.dropna() X_train = df_nonull[['Job Code','Job Level']]
> y_train = df_nonull[['Stock Value']]
> 
> 
> X_test = df[['Job Code','Job Level']] y_test = df[['Stock Value']]
> 
> regressor = LinearRegression() model=regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
> # display coefficients print(regressor.coef_)

> print(regressor.coef_)
```

Comment: I think what you want is called "imputation".  A simple way to do this is just to fill the NaN with the mean Stock Value of the Job Code.  However, if you are to believe there is some hidden structure in your data (for instance that stock value increases  with larger Code) this probably won't work.

Comment: Hi Demetri, Thanks for your answer -- since there is correlation between the Job Code, Job Level and Stock Value - I do not want to use "imputation". I would like to estimate the stock values keeping in mind that they are related to these 2 inputs, not just the mean.

Comment: Yea, ok that changes things.  I think linear regression is a suitable way to go about doing things.  Do you have any reason to expect that the relationship is linear?

Comment: No I can't assume that, regression was my first thought. So I am open to suggestions.

Comment: A walk through all of the possibilities would be a speculative tutorial beyond the realm of Stack Overflow; for that, you might try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward model training problem.  Your available training data (observations) are the rows with Stock Value present; your later "real" data are the rows without.

Categorical data is quite legal in such cases.  In fact, you might try declaring Job Level as categorical, as well, since it's discrete; that will free you from any assumptions of linearity (although it also denies any applicability of the level-code ordering).

Your task is to choose a model type that services your data properly.  This requires research and experimentation; welcome to Data Science.  Since you haven't discussed your data shape, density, connectivity, clustering, etc., there's really not much we can explore that with you.  Six observations on three features (note that Job Code and Job Title are not 100% coupled) is not enough for educated speculation.

Try adding some polynomial terms to your "linear" regression: perhaps a sqared term and a square root for each input.  That's often the first attempt for such a task.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: In particular, there are many such packages, and you're supposed to do that research *before* you ask the question.  Also, the packages cover different levels of involvement, and carry different model types.  You might look through SciKit / SciPy first, because there's a broad usage base.

Comment: There isn't a "which model"; as I said, you'll have to experiment.  You haven't given us a thorough problem description for us to weigh in.